# Using NDSolve to solve a Table of ODEs?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have the following `Table` of ODES:

```
Vector1=Range[-1,1,2/9]

ODEList1=Table[{theta[[i]]'[t]==Vector1[[i]]-K1/n*Sum[Sin[theta[[i]]-theta[[j]]],{j,1,Length[Vector1]}]},{i,1,Length[Vector1]}]
```

Is there an easy way to solve these with `NDSolve`?

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
K1=10;n=10;
System1=NDSolve[ODEList1,Table[Vector1[[i]],{i,1,Length[Vector1]}],{t,0,500}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to use indexed variables and add IC

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Vector1 = Range[-1, 1, 2/9];
depVars = Table[theta[i], {i, 1, Length[Vector1]}]
K1 = 10; n = 10;
ic = Table[theta[i][0] == 0, {i, 1, Length[Vector1]}]
ODEList1 = Table[{theta[i]'[t] == Vector1[[i]] - 
  K1/n*Sum[Sin[theta[i][t] - theta[j][t]], {j, 1, Length[Vector1]}]}, {i,1, Length[Vector1]}];

System1 = NDSolve[{ODEList1, ic}, depVars, {t, 0, 500}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am curious: what does Clear["Global`*"] do? I have seen this before but do not understand the logic behind it. Thank you!

Comment: @MathIsHard It clears all variables from global context. Good idea to use it before starting new code. You could also restart the kernel. They are not exactly the same. Restarting the kernel really cleans everything.